# R: bind_rows with unfd values

Tags: r, bind, plyr, na

I'm looking for an easy answer for the following:

Sample data, data4 and data3 are similar and data1 and data2 are similar:

```
 data4 <-                                            X__1       X__2
                                                     <chr>     <dbl>
                     No-C1-PG3.7-LDI0-LDE0-LB0.045-PDC0-D10  -12.27027
                     No-C0.95-PG3.7-LDI0-LDE0-LB0.045-PDC0-D10  Undf

 data1 <-                                        X__1       X__2
                Yes-C0.9-PG3.7-LDI0-LDE0-LB0.045-PDC0-D10 -12.2
                Yes-C0.85-PG3.7-LDI0-LDE0-LB0.045-PDC0-D10   20
                 Yes-C0.8-PG3.7-LDI0-LDE0-LB0.045-PDC0-D10 -15.2
                Yes-C0.75-PG3.7-LDI0-LDE0-LB0.045-PDC0-D10 -19.2
```

I'm trying to bind rows of two data sets:

```
data1 <- read_excel("~/location1.xlsx")
data2 <- read_excel("~/location2.xlsx")
data3 <- read_excel("~/location3.xlsx")
data4 <- read_excel("~/location4.xlsx")

YesFR <- rbind(data1,data2)
NoFR <- rbind(data3, data4)

Impact <- bind_rows(YesFR, NoFR)
```

I receive the following error: 
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Column `X__2` can't be converted from character to numeric

I think it has something to do with the Undf character in the data and that I need to convert it to NA. What is the most easy way of doing this and why does this message not occur when I bind data3 with data4?

Comment: What Im guessing is, `X_2` in `YesFR` is numeric and `X_2` in `NoFR` is character (since you have "Undf" in `data4`). Now `bind_rows` in `dplyr` gives output's the same type as the first input. So since `X_2` in `YesFR` is numeric, it tries to convert `X_2` in `NoFR` to numeric when binding, but fails. Try `bind_rows(NoFR, YesFR)` and see if it throws the same error message.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the data. try: `data4$X__2[data4$X__2=="Undf"] <- NA` and then try rbind again

Comment: @useR this gives the error Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Column X__2 can't be converted from numeric to character. But thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @ima So it confirms my guess that it fails because `X_2` is different type in the two datasets. @Matt L.'s suggestion should fix it.

Comment: @useR : with Matt's comment was able to change undf to NA, however I still receive the same error as stated in my original problem.

Comment: @MattL. I was able to change the undf to NA, but after running the model again same error appears. How can I provide you more information on the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to replace the `"Undf"` with a real `NA` because otherwise the column type must be character to include `"Undf"`. You could do this after loading but the better option is to make `"Undf"` equivalent to `NA` during the loading with `read_excel()`.

The `na` argument for `read_excel()` defaults to `na = ""` or empty cells. You can add to that argument something like

```
read_excel("~/location1.xlsx", na = c("", "Undf"))
```

Do this for each file and the binding should work fine.